# Angular UI Router - State params reset for parent when sharing controller in child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, state

I have ONE controller that is used by TWO child states (detail.Controller).

The parent states (`QUIZ1` & `QUIZ3`) have different controllers that push different data to the parent scopes (`quiz1.Controller` & `quiz3.Controller`)

**routes.js:**

```
{
      name: 'QUIZ1',
      abstract: true,
      url: '/quiz1',
      templateUrl: 'app/html-partials/quiz.html',
      controller: require('./app/controllers/quiz1.Controller').inject(angular.module('app', ['ui.router', require('angular-sanitize')]))
    },
    {
      name: 'QUIZ1.detail',
      url: '/:page',
      templateUrl: 'app/html-partials/quiz.detail.html',
      params: {
        page: {
          value: '0',
          squash: true
        },
        score: {
          value: '0',
          squash: true
        },
        timer: {
          value: false,
          squash: true
        }
      },
      controller: require('./app/controllers/detail.Controller').inject(angular.module('app', ['ui.router', require('angular-sanitize')]))
    },
    {
      name: 'QUIZ2',
      // some other state stuff
    },
    {
      name: 'QUIZ3',
      abstract: true,
      url: '/quiz3',
      templateUrl: 'app/html-partials/quiz.html',
      controller: require('./app/controllers/quiz3.Controller').inject(angular.module('app', ['ui.router', require('angular-sanitize')]))
    },
    {
      name: 'QUIZ3.detail',
      url: '/:page',
      templateUrl: 'app/html-partials/quiz.detail.html',
      params: {
        page: {
          value: '0',
          squash: true
        },
        score: {
          value: '0',
          squash: true
        },
        timer: {
          value: false,
          squash: true
        }
      },
      controller: require('./app/controllers/detail.Controller').inject(angular.module('app', ['ui.router', require('angular-sanitize')]))
    },
```

**quiz1.Controller.js: (parent controller that builds data)**

```
function buildData(resp) {
  $scope.slides = [];

  for (var item in resp.quiz_slides) {
    if (resp.quiz_slides) {
      $scope.slides.push(resp.quiz_slides[item]);
    }
  }
}
```

**detail.Controller.js: (partial where breakpoint is erroring):**

```
$scope.slide = $scope.slides[$stateParams.page];
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

When i navigate out of `QUIZ1.detail` with a `$state.go('QUIZ2')` and eventually into a page of `QUIZ3.detail` I get:

```
angular.js:14328 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This is relating to the $stateParams.page (used for navigation) I think as it's not correctly resetting because the old data might still be in the $scope.

**I KNOW THIS** because navigating IMMEDIATELY to `QUIZ3` will parse the data and no errors.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: You said, when you 'eventually' move into QUIZ2.detail - are you not going directly from QUIZ1.detail to QUIZ2.detail? Is there an intermediate state, or are you going through a parent? Possibly this is because children inherit params of their parents, but not the other way around.

Comment: @rrd, that's correct. It has to go through `QUIZ2` first and then into `QUIZ3` - I have updated the question to reflect this! How can it still be hanging on to `QUIZ1` stateParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if any one is wondering how I got around this, after putting it here and there and airing it to colleagues, I thought: "$rootScope for the slides"!

***NOTE:*** naming conventions differ slightly from answer, but you get the idea.

I introduced an init state in between the states so that it would properly parse the json stuff and throw the state into a new child called .detail:
**init-state.js:**

```
exports.inject = function (app) {
  app.controller('sevenIntAFFECTinit.Controller', exports.controller);
  exports.controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'jsonPartialService', '$log', '$rootScope'];
  return exports.controller;
};

exports.controller = function sevenIntAFFECTinitCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, jsonPartialService, $log, $rootScope) {
  // Do the json in here. Jokes
  $rootScope.slides = [];
  jsonPartialService
    .getJSON('part-1/7-INT-QUIZ-AFFECT')
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.prevState = response.prev_state;
      $scope.nextState = response.next_state;
      $scope.quizTitle = response.quiz_title;
      buildData(response);
    });
  function buildData(resp) {
    for (var item in resp.quiz_slides) {
      if (resp.quiz_slides) {
        $rootScope.slides.push(resp.quiz_slides[item]);
      }
    }
    $log.debug('after the slides have been pushed in init -->', $rootScope.slides);
    $state.go('7-INT-QUIZ-AFFECT.detail', $stateParams, {reload: true, inherit: false});
  }
};
```